# Should encodeURIComponent be used to encode parameters of post ajax request?

Tags: javascript, post

Should encodeURIComponent be used to encode parameters of post ajax request?

Thanks Yosef

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your request is using the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then **yes**, it should — POST fields are also in name value pairs, just like GET requests.  Special characters like `&`, `=`, `[`, `]`, etc need to be encoded just the same.

Comment: Sure? Does it depend on what reads the data server side? Unless there are automated magic I didn't notice, I don't encode when doing POST in our app.

Comment: @Mic: when working with form data, separated by ampersands, yes.  If you're just working with the raw POST data, then no (but this is still no different to GET).

Comment: you're right that's what we do, we send a JSON string as raw data and don't need to encode it.

Comment: @JDelage: because they're accessing the *raw* data at the server, so if it were encoded then they would need to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you never know when an ampersand is plotting against you.